# GParted: Add disk space from another non-use disk

Tags: 16.04, gparted, disk, disk-management

i'm new in ubuntu, and i need to increase my '/' space from another non-use partition:
- From my /dev/sda9 partition to my /dev/sda8
How can i do this? Here's a screenshot of my partitions structure:
[image]

Comment: Since there is such a large space in between sda8 & sda9 it is recommended to back your data in sda6 & sda9 before moving the partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to shrink `sda9`, making a free space to appear. Then the problem falls down to the fact that the free space should be adjacent to `sda8`. So you need to repeatedly move every partition in between `sda9` and `sda8` so that free space would approach to `sda8`, until they become adjacent. And finally, just extend `sda8` to the freespace.

I'd recommend to backup important data, as there's always risk of something going wrong, like electricity turning off, etc.

Also note: if one of those partition is the system you're currently running, then you need to do it from a live cd, like Ubuntu *(idk whether it have gparted installed though)*, or [Gparted live cd](http://gparted.org/livecd.php), because how otherwise the system would access its binaries, whilst partition being unmounted and resized.

Comment: for future installations use lvm. for now boot a live cd and use gparted to shrink, move and grow your partitions. backup your date first, gparted worked for me everytime but things can (and will) go wrong.